# Golf Par Probabilities

Tags: probability

The chance that a golfer will break par during a tournament round is 3/7.  Of 4 golfers in a 4some, how many golfers can expect to break par during one round?

So the answer would be: 4(3/7)=12/7... so 1? can expect to break par during one round. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The expected number of golfers breaking par during one round is $4\cdot(3/7) = 12/7$. It doesn't have to be a whole number. For example, if you throw a die, then the expected number of dots you see is $3.5$.

Remember what expectation means. If you do the experiment with the golfers a 1000 times and calculate the average number of golfers breaking par during one round, you will probably get something close to $12/7$. As 1000 gets bigger, it will become more and more probable that you get something close to $12/7$, until in the limit you get $12/7$  "almost surely". This is the law of large numbers.

Comment: Oh ok, yea that's the part I wasn't sure about, if it had to be a whole number or not. Thanks!